load_only and upgrade SQLAlchemy from 1.4.32 to 2.0.3
Despite seeing many answers to my question it does not work for me.
Working with SQLAlchemy 1.4.32 the following works:
columns = ['name','address','city']
u_view = UserView.query.options(load_only(*columns)).all()

To get this working with SQLAlchemy 2.0.3 I've read (see expected ORM mapped attribute for loader strategy argument Python SQLAlchemy) I should do:
columns = ['name','address','city']
u_view = UserView.query.options(
           load_only([getattr(UserView, c) for c in columns])
         ).all()

But doing this i get:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: expected ORM mapped attribute for loader strategy argument

What should be the correct code for SQLAlchemy > 2?
(Note: using UserView.name, UserView.address etc.. as arguments to load_only works but I want to keep using this columns variable..)
Kind regards.

Solved it. I needed:  *[getattr .... in stead of [getattrs...

You can post it as an answer and accept it
